# Angular 2 - how to use function from another component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Imagine that we have 3 components and one of them has some function which I want to use in other components. All these components are on the same level (siblings).

```
file1.ts
export class ComponentWithFunction() {
    function getData() {
        console.log('data has been fetched');
    }
}

file2.ts
export class ComponentA() {
    // here I want to have possibility to use getData
}

file3.ts
export class ComponentB() {
    // here I want to have possibility to use getData
}
```

What should I do to have an access to getData function from other component? I know that I can create SharedService and Inject it into specified components but is there any other way like using static functions or something like that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Why Component ?** Angular 2 says, that you must to use services for retrieving data and refactoring data access to a separate service keeps the component lean and focused on supporting the view. It also makes it easier to unit test the component with a mock service.

You can put it into the `service` and `inject` that `service` in each `Component` in which you want to use that function.

Add that service into the `app module's providers` and inject in the constructors like

```
file1.ts

@Injectable()
export class ComponentWithFunction() {
    function getData() {
        console.log('data has been fetched');
    }
}

file2.ts
export class ComponentA() {
    constructor(private service: ComponentWithFunction)
}

file3.ts
export class ComponentB() {
    constructor(private service: ComponentWithFunction)
}
```

For more see [**Service in Angular 2**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always use services to retrieve data

See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html
"We create a reusable service to manage our hero data calls"

Comment: @user3844198 if this helps you, you can mark as correct and help others to find it easily

Answer (score 0):

So, maybe different example.

Let's say that I have Component responsible for Modal Element on page. 
Context of such component has a logic, methods like open, close, refresh and so on.

As I understand well, to use open() or close() method from different component, I have to create Modal as a service and Inject it into all places where I want to use it right? No option to subscribe the event / method from Modal ?

Comment: See here. You need to add your modal component into another one yes? So you can give to your modal component a template variable like `<modal #myModal></modal` and get that element in your component with `@ViewChild('myModal') modal`. And all public functions on that modal component will be accessible in your component via `modal`